# How create a new instance of a Model that is registered with a Controller?

Tags: extjs, model, controller, extjs4, extjs4.2

### What is the idiomatic way to create a new Instance of an associated Model inside a Controller?

#### Motivation:

If I change the `Class` of my `Model` the code below doesn't get updated and I have to find all the breakages and fix them manually.

If I could use the the association in the controller, it gets updated automatically, but I can't find any documentation on the magical incantation to create a new instance from the controller reference.

Here is the relevant parts of my controller:

```
Ext.define('AdminApp.controller.SelectFilesController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    models: [
        'File'
    ],

    // lots of stuff snipped for brevity

    onFilefieldChange: function(filefield, value, eOpts) {
        Ext.each(Ext.getDom('select-upload-button-fileInputEl').files, function(f) {
                var fm = new AdminApp.model.File({
                    name: f.name,
                    size: f.size,
                    type: f.type,
                    md5: '',
                    status: 0
                });
            }
        });

    // lots more stuff snipped for brevity 
}
```

#### What I want to know:

I found this in the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/mvc_pt3):

> It’s important to note that the getters for both views and models
>   return a reference to the class (requiring you to instantiate your own
>   instances), while the getters for stores and controllers return actual
>   instances.

### I can't find any examples of what the code to instantiate an instance should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### After much trial and error and just plain educated guessing ...

I figured out what the syntax should be.

First you need to create a reference to the `class` of the `Model`.

By convention this is the name of the model prefixed with `get` and suffixed with `Model`.

```
var fmc = this.getFileModel();
```

I had to do this outside the `Ext.each()` function that visits each item because the `this` reference pointed to an HTML5 `File` object instead of my `Controller`.

Then you simply use a regular `Ext.create(fmc, { /* config */ }` to get a new instance like so.

```
var fm = Ext.create(fmc, {
    name: f.name,
    size: f.size,
    type: f.type,
    md5: '',
    status: 0
});
```

So the correct version of the `onFilefieldChange` function in the question should look like:

```
onFilefieldChange: function(filefield, value, eOpts) {
    var fmc = this.getFileModel();
    Ext.each(Ext.getDom('select-upload-button-fileInputEl').files, function(f) {
            var fm = Ext.create(fmc,{
                name: f.name,
                size: f.size,
                type: f.type,
                md5: '',
                status: 0
            });
        }
    });
}
```